# Is there any way to override the argument insertion for default Spring validation error messages?

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

[Specifying `required="true"` in a Spring Web Flow `<binding>` element](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html#view-binder) seems to use a default error message that inserts the field name into the message. I'm hoping there's a way to instead use that field name as a key to get a descriptive name for the field.

I know that I can [override the entire error message with a property like `fieldname.required`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/webflow/validation/WebFlowMessageCodesResolver.html), but that would require me to repeat the text "is required" for each field.

I've looked through the source code but haven't yet found a magic key to use to get the field name converted to a field description and plugged into the existing default error message.

I can, of course, do this with code in a custom validator, but I'd really like to use this configurable approach instead if possible.